# How do I get maxima to show me its working / intermediate steps

Tags: maxima

Maxima often does calculations in one pass that if I were doing myself I might put in intermediate steps, e.g.

```
integrate(sin(theta)^2, theta);
```

in this case diff(%,theta) will give me the crucial observation that 2*sin(x)^2=1-cos(2x), but more generally, is there any way to get maxima to explain what intermediate transformations it has done in order to get to its answer?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Maxima cannot display intermediate steps.